# I am confused to use have got in the sentence: "so you have got here at last!"

Tags: have-got

This phrase from "The Hobbit". 
"So you *have got* here at last!" That was what he was going to say Gandalf this time. But it was not Gandalf.

Comment: Can you clarify your queston please. What is unclear? Why do you mention Gandalf?

Comment: _Got here_ means _arrived_. You are linking the wrong pair of words together.

Comment: @HotLicks Not in British English it wouldn't!!

Comment: What are you actually asking?

Comment: @Hot Licks - The quoted text is from the UK edition of the book, so it uses British English. I wouldn't be surprised if the American editions used "gotten" along with changing to American spellings, but the OP is obviously not reading that edition.

But really, the claim that Tolkien couldn't write English is absurd, given what he did for a living... I'm not a fan of his novels, but his English was never "incorrect".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## get!

The verb is an intransitive (no subject) form of "to get" that has the meaning of movement:

- to **get** (v): to succeed in coming or going : to bring or move oneself

This is the same verb as used in common phrases such as "I got out of town", or "get over here!". The most literal translation is "bring yourself". As the verb is intransitive, there's no subject, so it's normally followed with a clause (e.g. a positional word like "here", "out", "there") to indicate the destination.

Your quote contains the past perfect of get, "**have got**" indicating a completed action:

- "So you **have got** here at last!" 
  = "So you **have brought yourself** here at last!"

The tone of this is not particularly polite or deferential, and would be considered rude if used to a stranger. The author used it to convey that the speaker was annoyed with the person (he thought) he was speaking to.

#### have got / have gotten

It's worth mentioning that there are two forms of get in the perfect tense:

- to have got
- to have gotten

Both forms are recognised as grammatically correct by native speakers (although some will try to argue the point), and both have exactly the same meaning. The "got" form is the most common in British English, while American English seems to use "gotten" form more for the perfect tense.  If you're learning English, you may only have encountered "gotten", which would explain a difficulty in parsing that sentence.

It is incorrect to use "gotten" in the simple past tense (i.e., you can say "I have finally gotten here", but don't say "I finally gotten here")